# YouTube Player API - Seek and then play

Tags: javascript, youtube

I'm having an issue when trying to use `.seekTo()` with the YouTube Player API. The first time I set the `.seekTo()` the video will correctly seek to the value (e.g. 4 seconds) and then play [without me issuing `.playVideo()`].  The video is stopped when I call `.seekTo()` the 2nd time and the video plays from the start. I want to be able to start the video again from the seek location.

Comment: I think I've got to the bottom of this.  If you use .stopVideo() then .seekTo() doesn't work after that - if you use .pauseVideo() and then .seekTo() it works as expected

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<scriptm src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="player"></div>
<div>
  <button id="btnSeek" data-seek="30.7">Seek 30</button>
  <button id="btnSeek" data-seek="60">Seek 60</button>
  <button id="btnSeek" data-seek="90">Seek 90</button>
  <button id="btnSeek" data-seek="180">Seek 180</button>
</div>

<script>
$.getScript('//www.youtube.com/iframe_api');
 var player;
 function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
     player = new YT.Player('player', {
       height: '390',
       width: '640',
       videoId: '-HjpL-Ns6_A',
         playerVars: { 'start': 159, 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 1, 'showinfo': 0, 'rel': 0 },
       events: {
         'onReady': onPlayerReady,
         'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
       } 
     });         
 }
 var done = false;
 function onPlayerStateChange(evt) 
 {
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
 }
 function onPlayerReady(evt) {

    // doesn't work here
    // player.seekTo(30);  

     // lets make ure we have a function
     //alert("typeof(player.SeekTo) = " + typeof(player.seekTo));
 }
 function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }

 $(function() {

$(document).on('click', '#btnSeek', function() {
   if(player.getCurrentTime() == player.getDuration())
   {
     player.playVideo();
   }
    player.seekTo($(this).data('seek'), true);
});
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: When the video is paused/stopped - clicking the Seek buttons does seek to the correct point but I also need the video to play without pressing the play button on the player

Comment: When the video is stopped and click on the seek button than you can check video duration is equal video current time, it is equal to the first of all video has played than after will seek the video.

if(player.getCurrentTime() == player.getDuration())
   {
     player.playVideo();
   }